# Unexpected token error from import statement in cucumber

Tags: angular, typescript, cucumber

I am attempting to create Angular e2e testing using Cucumber and chai.  When I run the tests with 'ng e2e', the E/launcher encounters an error.

I've tried comparing the file to guides/tutorials on the internet but I am new to cucumber and can't seem to find any references to the issue.

protractor.conf.js

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/features/**/*.feature'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./src/steps/**/*.steps.ts'],
  }
};
```

app.feature

```
Feature: Go to the home
  Display the title

  Scenario: Home Page
    Given I am on the home page
    When I do nothing
    Then I should see the title
```

app.po.ts

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get(browser.baseUrl) as Promise<any>;
  }

  getTitleText() {
    return element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText() as Promise<string>;
  }
}
```

app.steps.ts

```
import { Before, Given, Then, When } from 'cucumber';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import { AppPage } from '../app.po';

let page: AppPage;

Before(() => {
  page = new AppPage();
});

Given(/^I am on the home page$/, async () => {
  await page.navigateTo();
});

When(/^I do nothing$/, () => {});

Then(/^I should see the title$/, async () => {
  expect(await page.getTitleText()).to.equal('TopicCreationFrontEnd');
});
```

I was expecting it to run but instead this is the terminal output that I am getting:

```
[11:07:51] E/launcher - Error: /Users/n0361431/Developments/Workspaces/Angular/topic-creation-front-end/e2e/src/steps/app.steps.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Before, Given, Then, When } from 'cucumber';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at supportCodePaths.forEach.codePath (/Users/n0361431/Developments/Workspaces/Angular/topic-creation-front-end/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js:142:42)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Cli.getSupportCodeLibrary (/Users/n0361431/Developments/Workspaces/Angular/topic-creation-front-end/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js:142:22)
    at /Users/n0361431/Developments/Workspaces/Angular/topic-creation-front-end/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js:169:41
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/n0361431/Developments/Workspaces/Angular/topic-creation-front-end/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js:44:103)
[11:07:51] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Comment: On the config - the cucumberopts syntax is incorrect  - try with cucumberOpts: {
    'require': ['./src/steps/**/*.steps.ts']
  }

Comment: @iQuain did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not provided inside protractor.config.js for TS
add below callback function to initiate.

```
onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
          project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')
        });
      }
```